# expected identifier error in Xcode mail

Tags: objective-c

Here is my code:

```
-(void) sendEmailTo:(NSString *)to withSubject:(NSString *) subject withBody:(NSString *)body {
NSString *mailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:?to=%@&subject=%@&body=%@",
                        [to stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
                        [subject stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
                        [body  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mailString]];
}

-(void) send:(id) sender {
[self sendEmailTo:[phoneNumberEntry @"@txt.att.net"] withSubject:[settingsSubjectBox] withBody:[settingsMsgBox]];
}

-(IBAction)launchBomb:(id)sender {
sender;
}
```

in the "void send sender" brackets, there is a "expected identifier" error. how do i fix?

Comment: do yo uneed the :(id) sender ??

Answer (score 1):

```
[self sendEmailTo:[phoneNumberEntry @"@txt.att.net"] withSubject:[settingsSubjectBox] withBody:[settingsMsgBox]];
```

Well to be honest I'm not sure what is going on on that entire line ^^. For example, `withSubject:[settingsSubjectBox]` doesn't make any sense. If this is supposed to be a method call, it should look something like this `withSubject:[self settingsSubjectBox]`. Or if it's reading the value of a property, like this `withSubject:self.settingsSubjectBox`.

Either way, `withSubject:[settingsSubjectBox]` is invalid syntax. I recommend rewriting the entire line because this problem exists for every argument on the line.

Comment: I have phoneNumberEntry is a textbox containing a phone number, settingsSubjectBox is a textbox containing the subject, and settingsMsgBox is a textbox containing the message. the goal of all of this is to send the person a sms through emailing them (this is for a att phone. does that help?